# IPythonblocks - can i run from within Ipython without notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Ipython and the IDE runs fine.  from the command line on mac terminal i have also installed ipythonblocks using easy_install command:

```
easy_install ipythonblocks
```

For instructions you can click [ipythonblocks](https://github.com/jiffyclub/ipythonblocks)

does ipythonblocks only run in ipython notebook.  I also tried notebook but my web interface from chrome is not letting me get to a notebook:

running 'ipython notebook' from the command line yields this localhost webpage:
[image]

My issue is whenever the following simple script is executed it fails:

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

from ipythonblocks import BlockGrid

print "hello everyone."


grid = BlockGrid.from_web('zcezcM')



the error that i see in the console is the following:

runfile('/Users/christopher/.spyder2/temp.py', wdir='/Users/christopher/.spyder2')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-bfba2859d45e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/christopher/.spyder2/temp.py', wdir='/Users/christopher/.spyder2')

  File "/Users/christopher/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/christopher/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 78, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/christopher/.spyder2/temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ipythonblocks import BlockGrid

ImportError: No module named ipythonblocks
```

my end goal is just to confirm that ipythonblocks is installed and i am able to visually run it and see results from scripts.

Comment: I'd guess that Spyder is using a different Python installation from the one where `easy_install` installed ipythonblocks. In the notebook interface, clicking New > Notebooks: Python 2 should get you a new notebook.